# How to repair topology of a shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geometry, intersection, topology, envi

I performed an object-based image analysis using ENVI EX, and each of the classified features were exported as a shapefile. I transferred those shapefiles into ArcMap 10, and tried to intersect them with other shapefiles of the same area that were acquired from [GeoBase](http://www.geobase.ca/geobase/en/index.html).

When I try to run the intersect tool, I get an error message stating that the topology of the shapefiles extracted from ENVI EX is invalid. I tried to turn on the topology tool to repair the topology of those shapefiles, but the buttons are greyed out, and I can't seem to click on them. The topology tool does not work for any of the shapefiles that I have.

Any solutions? How can I fix the topology and run the intersect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I encountered similar issues as well with polygons. Maybe you have a similar problem.

**Error Message by ESRI**: "Invalid Topology (Incomplete Void Poly)"

**Actual Error**: "Invalid Geometry"

**Fix**: Run "Repair Geometry" (changes data in-place, be careful, there is no undo)

What happens is that the error reported is not using the ESRI terminology of Topology/Geometry and confuses everyone. In my case, while the error was talking about topologies, there were no topologies defined (topology as in an ESRI topology). But when I checked the geometry (using the "Check Geometry" tool) I found out that my geometry (as in an ESRI geometry) there were errors.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case ArcMap doesn't work, you might want to try GRASS' [v.clean tool.](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.clean.html) You can install GRASS with QGIS. After installing:

> **[Cleaning of topology of a SHAPE file using the GRASS Toolbox](http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/QGIS_GRASS_Cookbook#Example%3a_Cleaning_of_topology_of_a_SHAPE_file_using_the_GRASS_Toolbox)**
>
> 1. Load the SHAPE file into QGIS
> 2. Use existing GRASS mapset (or create a new one) with matching projection settings
> 3. Now you have to transfer the SHAPE file from QGIS to GRASS using Toolbox -> File management -> Import into GRASS -> Import vector into
>      GRASS -> Import vector into GRASS from QGIS view (v.in.ogr.qgis). Some
>      topological problems may be reported depending on the quality of your
>      SHAPE file.
> 4. These topological problems we can fix now in GRASS via toolbox using the topology tools: Vector -> Develop map -> Toolset for
>      cleaning topology of vector map -> v.clean.break. Define a threshold
>      in map units (for example 0.5 [m] or likewise). Analyse the printed
>      report, probably the threshold needs to be adjusted or a different
>      topology cleanup tool to be used. Click then on view output to show
>      the result as map.
> 5. Export the cleaned map to SHAPE format: File management -> Export from GRASS -> Export vector from GRASS -> v.out.ogr